# Change color scale in gvisMotionChart

Tags: r, googlevis

See the code:

```
library(googleVis)
M1 <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", timevar="Year", colorvar = "Profit",
                      xvar = "Sales", yvar =  "Expenses")
plot(M1)
```

When you select a numeric variable as the colorvar like I did above, googleVis sets red color to represent high values, green to represent middle values and blue to represent low values.

But what if I wanted it the other way around? How do I change the color scale to different colors or a different palette?